# In Spanish 'Ocho' means 'eight', or 'Ocho' means 'eight' in English?

Tags: grammar, word-order

I only picked the number eight to shorten the title, but this question is for any scenario where you are explaining to someone what something means in another language.  I've heard this said both ways, in one case it was on sesame street. The character said (sang),

> "No me gusta. (In Spanish that means, 'I don't like')"

The above seems wrong to me, but I would think an educational show would be sure to use the correct version.  Off the top of my head I can't think where I heard the other way, I think it was on an episode of "The X-Files". It was something along the lines of...

> "Scully, 'blah blah blah' means Alien in English."

I wasn't sure how to tag this question.

Comment: "Ocho means eight in Spanish". You're already speaking in English so there's no need to mention it, and the hearer will recognize which word ('ocho') is not English, so the foreign language needs to be specified.

Comment: Sorry, I need to fix my question title.

Answer (score 4):

As for your title, I think "Ocho means eight in Spanish" is correct.

I think this because:

This sentence is correct:

> "Ocho" is the Spanish word for "eight." (or "Ocho is Spanish for eight")

But this:

> "Ocho" is English for "eight."

is of course incorrect.

If you reword that sentence to include the word "means," I think it should follow the same pattern.

> "Ocho" means "eight" in Spanish.

Comment: Sorry, I reread my title and I had incorrectly ordered the words in a way that didn't match my question.  I've updated the title.

Answer (score 1):

Consider saying instead:

> "*Ocho* is ([the](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=C-uiAK74XpsC&pg=PA175&lpg=PA175&dq=%22granza+is+the+spanish+for%22&source=bl&ots=XJfDZ4dPqW&sig=PVvxNfNctSTWx30Vsss7HnDHDqE&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=w9WEU9ymJsaN0AWPjYCQCg&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22granza%20is%20the%20spanish%20for%22&f=false)) Spanish for *eight*."

Comment: "the Spanish"? Shouldn't that just be "Spanish"?

Comment: @Bart Indeed. "The" Spanish. What's "the" English for "ocho?"